# Error when running the tune function from the e1071 package in R: "object 'R_svmtrain' not found"

Tags: r, svm

I'm attempting to use the `tune` function from the `e1071` package and I'm being told an object called `R_svmtrain` doesn't exist, but I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests how I should create the object. Here's some code that reproduces this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(e1071)
train_y <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
train_x <- as.matrix(mtcars[,-2])

tune(svm, train_x, train_y, kernel = "radial", 
ranges = list(cost = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000), gamma = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4)))

Error in svm.default(c(15.5, 19.2, 15.2, 10.4, 17.3, 27.3, 15.8, 22.8,  : 
object 'R_svmtrain' not found
```

Comment: What does `getAnywhere(R_svmtrain)` return?

Comment: I get `no object named ‘R_svmtrain’ was found`.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `e1071`?

Comment: The problem went away after re-installing. Thanks!

Comment: I had this issue and re-installing worked (~ 2017-10-15). Today (2017-10-20) the same error was kicked and once more a reinstall was required. I suppose a bug ticket is in order.